# Сохранение текста

Tags: java, awt

Всем привет. Написал код для сохранения текста, который пользователь пишет в текстовом поле `JTextArea`. При нажатии кнопки `Restore`, должен выводиться текст, который был сохранен, но этого не происходит. Притом в файле `Saved.ser` сам текст не отображается вместо него абракадабра. Подскажите, что нужно сделать?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestSer implements Serializable {
    JTextArea text;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestSer testSer = new TestSer();
        testSer.go();
    }
    public void go() { 

        int width = 10;
        int height = 20;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save me"); //Графическая часть
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        text = new JTextArea(width, height);
        JButton buttonSave = new JButton("Save");
        JButton buttonRestore = new JButton("Restore");
        Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonSave);
        panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, buttonBox);
        panel.add(text);

        buttonSave.addActionListener(new Saver());
        buttonSave.addActionListener(new Restore());
        buttonBox.add(buttonRestore);
        buttonBox.add(buttonSave);

    }
    public class Saver implements ActionListener { // Сохранение
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
           try {
           FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Saved.ser");
           ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
           os.writeObject(text);
           os.close();
           } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
    public class Restore implements ActionListener { // Загрузка
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            try {
            FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("Saved.ser");
            ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fileStream);
            Object one = os.readObject();
            JTextArea text = (JTextArea) one;
            os.close();
            } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При сохранении, вот в этой строке:

```
os.writeObject(text);
```

Вы сохраняете совсем не текст, а объект типа `JTextArea` (так как Ваша переменная `text` имеет тип `JTextArea`).

Для сохранения текста, который содержится в `JTextArea`, сначала этот текст необходимо получить (при помощи метода `getText()` объекта `JTextArea`).

Потоки `FileInputStream` и `FileOutputStream` используются для манипуляции *сырыми* бинарными данными. Для ввода/вывода текста лучше использовать `FileReader` и `FileWriter` соответственно.

Таким образом, сохранение можно реализовать так:

```
public class Saver implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Saved.ser");
            fileWriter.write(text.getText());
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

А загрузку вот так:

```
public class Restore implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Saved.ser"));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(currentLine);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            text.setText(stringBuffer.toString());

        } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно понимать разницу между объектом типа `JTextArea` (Это графический компонент, часть интерфейса, со своими методами и кучей данных, помимо собственно отображаемого текста) и собственно текстом, который в нем отображается. Вы, видимо, хотите сохранить не графический элемент, а введенный в него текст - а иначе смысл вашей задумки вообще непонятен. Для сохранения собственно текста нужно

1. получить его из `JTextArea` (используя, например, метод `getText()` );
2. Записать его в простой текстовый файл (используя, напр. класс `PrintStream`).

Вы же записываете в файл сложный объект (компонент GUI) со всеми его потрохами, которые вам совершенно не нужны - это и есть та абракадабра, которую вы видите в файле.

Дальше, для восстановления текста вам надо прочитать сохраненный текст из файла (используя, напр. класс `FileReader`) и отобразить его в вашем `JTextArea`. Это можно сделать методом setText().

Вы же вместо этого зачем-то создаёте новый локальный объект: `JTextArea text = (JTextArea) one;`, который нигде потом не используется. Это не тот `JTextArea text`, который описан у вас в начале программы, это новая локальная переменная. Читайте про области видимости и локальные переменные. Да и вообще про классы - разберитесь, чем String отличается от JTextArea.